# Deleting Entire rows with if when there are more than 2 duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Before][image: After]

It's probably something simple I've over looked but I think I need some fresh eyes on it. I've setup a formula that sets duplicates as either "K" to keep or "D" to delete. It works fine if there are only 2 duplicates but if there are 3 or more it will delete only 1 duplicate leaving the rest. Any help would be greatly Appreciated!

```
Set wsl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
lr = wsl.Range("A" & wsl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For d = 2 To lr
    If wsl.Range("J" & d).Value Like "*D*" Then
       wsl.Range("J" & d).EntireRow.Delete
Else
End If
Next d
```

Comment: If  you're deleting rows, it's recommended to start at the *end* and work your way upwards. `For d = lr to 2 Step -1 // ...`

Comment: Thanks! that was it! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Try changing the .value like "*D*" to .value = "D" and also begin deleting from bottom to top. I don’t have my computer to show you, but you can find multiple examples here in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting rows, you should start at the end, and work toward the top.  You should just need to change your `For` loop beginning to

```
For d = lr to 2 Step -1
```

If you use <kbd>F8</kbd> to step through the code as you have it, you'll notice that when you delete a row, that row under it becomes the "current row".  Your code then immediately moves on to the *next* row, without checking the one you brought up a row.

Working from the end, to the start, avoids this issue.